# packaging & deploying Java EE webapp without ANT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant

We are going to develop a huge webapp coded in Java EE technology for our client. My client doesn't support ANT and Eclipse which are OSS in their servers.

So our requirement is to code and develop the application in our local system and test it, then we need to supply the source code in the client server where we will run a deployment script which will compile the required java files from the source files and deploy the .class files and other resource files to Tomcat running on that server (HP-UX).

Is it possible to use just javac, jar or other commands available in JAVA_HOME/bin to deploy an application with out using ANT scripts? If there is any such implementation could you please guide us? I wonder before ANT was developed, how JAVA developers used to deploy big applications. I came to know that MAKE command (available in our server) is not good for java applications.

Note: We will be having complex package hierarchy (up to 4 levels)

**UPDATE:** It looks like I dont have a straight forward answer. I would like to persuade our client to use ANT. If not I will develop a cross platform custom build tool for my client based up on the comments below... Thanks guys.. I dont think building that type of tool is not that difficult if we know the proper steps in packaging and deployments...

Comment: Why do you need to build it at the client server? Would it not be more natural to deliver a war or an ear file?

Comment: Yes, we can do that. But client requires only source files. Lets say, we provide source and .war file. But in future if they want to maintain the application by themselves, they can't, because they dont allow OSS like ANT, ECLIPSE to be installed in their developers systems....

Comment: You can write script on python, ruby-rake, perl or at least shell script

Comment: Just say no to the client. Even HP-UX Java itself is based on open-source OpenJDK. What they are asking is insane. Build tools such as Ant are not present at run-time, nor are they distributed with a war file, so there is no reason to ban them. Imagine, even Linux itself as a development/deployment platform would be disallowed by your client.

Comment: This sounds like an unreasonable requirement by the client. There's nothing stopping you providing the source code with the built binary, but forcing you to build a custom build tool as part of the contract is unreasonable and demonstrates a lack of Java knowledge by the client. ANT is as standard a build tool as they come... I could almost understand an objection to Maven...

Comment: ya, my client is a big health insurance payor and they worry too much about member data. All the 80% of the software was developed in proprietary MF COBOL and remaining 20% was developed in JAVA for screens. They accepted JAVA for screens and Tomcat because their vendor who provided the main software certified that those OSS wont cause any security breach...

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole setup is pretty strange but anyhow...

A .war file is pretty simple. It's a ZIP file with a given directory structure. You can easily create this with a shell script that first runs `javac` to compile the source code, then copies the file to the correct directory and finally packs it into a ZIP file with the .war extension.

You'll find the specification for .war files on the net. Or you can build one in your environment, open it with a ZIP tool and have a look which files need to go where.

**Update:** If your application is big, then you can split it into modules. Each module will be compiled and packaged into a separate .jar file (basically a ZIP file as well). If a module depends on another then, then just pass the required .jar files as the class path argument to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have been doing the same for small application where I used javac command for each package independently then using jar command to package it. But our code is put into more multiple packages... and the JAVA files are dependent on other java files (Super classes) from other package. So in that case a single javac command would not compile the whole source from src/ folder. And moreover, over the time a new package can be included...(must be scalable).

Comment: @Venkatesh: You can also work with .jar files. See my update above.

Comment: Thanks for your update. But here is a situation. JAVA1 file in PACKAGE1 is a subclass to the JAVA2 file in PACKAGE2. And JAVA3 file in PACKAGE2 is a subclass to the JAVA4 file in PACKAGE1. in that case which package has to be compiled first?

Comment: They need to be compiled at the same time and they cannot go into separate .jar files. That holds for whatever development environment you use.

Comment: You can write script on python, ruby-rake, perl or at least shell script

Comment: we don't have python, ruby.. Shell and perl scripts available. But could you guide me on how to do that based up on my problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must accept the client requirements then this is probably how I would do it.

To avoid having to modify dependencies for each and every file you add I would introduce a convention of where to put source code, jar files and output files. Then I would create a script with a few settings:

1. Name of war.
2. List of library locations.
3. List of source roots, maybe letting the folder name of the root be the jar file name.

Then when running the script it would create a class path including all jar files presented in the library locations list. Then it would for each source location compile the java files, build a jar and add the jar file to the class path (in case later modules needs it).

Finally it would build a web app structure with the external libraries, the newly created jars, copy over the asp files (possibly precompiled) and then using zip package the web app structure into a war file.

Find out which shells are acceptable by the customers so you don't use any shell specific features. I don't think you need anything fancy, so that should not be too hard.

Comment: Thanks Roger. I would like to implement a custom build tool for the client based up on above guidelines. We still persuade our client to use ANT.